# Heatmap based on values of points

Tags: qgis, point, heat-map, hot-spot

I have these points on Energy performance and I want to create a heatmap in QGIS following the same logic in the colour scheme.

[image: Energy performance points]

[image: key]

I would like to create a heatmap ideally a vector or raster based on these values, like the example below.

[image: heatmap]

I know there is a plugin in QGIS but which steps do I need to take so that my raster has the same values as my points?

Answer (score 3):

Heatmaps from point-layers can be easily done in layer-styling: select heatmap as layer rendering style
[image]

Optionally define a field from the attributes for weighting (highlighted on the screenshot below). Select of define an appropriate color-ramp and set the color of the leftermost marker to transparent (otherwise, you will have no "white" space around your points or point-clusters). Change values for radius and max-value to adapt the picture and set the rendering quality to "best" when done.
[image]

Comment: I have used this but it doesn't allow you to colour the heatmap based on the exact values you want, you can just control the field that has the weights

Comment: You can try to use Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation): go to the toolbox and filter for Heatmap. With this, you create a raster output (grayscale) where you can use all the styling (single channel pseudo-color): there, you have better options to control the relationship between color and values. Does that help?