# Interpolating 0-1 (presence / absence) point data in a vector using QGIS "3.20"

Tags: qgis, interpolation, heat-map

I would like to make a heatmap using presence absence data (imported as a CSV file) for koalas but I can't work out how to do it.

Here is the raw data (presence ) map

[image]

This is the kind of map I created in ArcMap:

[image]

[image: This is the menu I found in QGIS 3.20]

The Heatmap option creates a blank white layer:

[image]

Heatmap with adjusted Radius still not working

@JR helped me to get the scale right:   Radius 0.005,    Pixel Size: 0.000005

[image]

[image]

Adjusted the Symbology and Transparency = Looking Good !

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Are you set on a heat map? These are most useful for analyzing continuous variables and checking the spatial coincidence of high or low clusters. Your data are dichotomous- that is categorical with only 2 classes- absent or present. Why not start with a dot plot of presence and absence, then see if there is any clustering?

Comment: Thanks Leigh  I have added a map I created in ARCGIS to give you an idea of what kind of map I want to create in QGIS

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/359389/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381393/88814 for how to create a heatmap.

Comment: Thanks Babel,  I could not find the links you provided  in QGIS version 3.20.  The box I found is as follows:

Comment: Thanks Babel,  I could not find the links you provided  in QGIS version 3.20.  The box I found is as follows:   Heatmap (Kernal Density Estimation) and has Parameters: Point Layer, Radius, Output Raster Size However when I use this the map goes blank.

Comment: I have added the Heatmap Menu from QGIS version 3.2 so you can see the options I have . They always create a blank white layer

Comment: This is a crs issue, your koala layer is using degrees as unit so your ten radius unit is way to big, you need to input a lower value   to get a result (in fact you should reproject your layer to a projected crs so you could input a meaningful radius in a known unit)

Comment: Thanks JR Changing the Heatmap Radius doesnt seem to help, Using a radius of anywhere between 5 and 1 will project a white background with the original points on it ???

Comment: At the equator 1 degree is close to 111km this is still too big, also your raster output setting need adjusting ( more pixel and smaller pixel size), I strongly suggest to project your data to a meter based crs, it will be easier to set sensible number

Comment: Thanks JR I adjusted the pixel size and now I have a white circle in the middle... How do I change  to a meter based crs ?

Comment: BIG THANKS to JR   ---   I finally got the scale right:   Radius 0.005,    Pixel Size: 0.000005

Comment: Still keen to change the projection to a meter based crs (I have changed the measures to metric measures)

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your questions here.